# How to add an event Listener to multiple objects via the class name

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a set of scrolling objects with text in them. I have surrounded said text with a div and a class name of "scrollContent". I have added an onscroll attribute that calls my method.

I have come across the .addEventListener feature and want to add a listener when any divs with the class name scrollContent is scrolled, call my function.

Is this possible and how?

```
function checkScroll(scrollEle) {

     var topLG = getTopLG(scrollEle);

     if(scrollEle.scrollTop < 10){
     topLG.style.display = "none";
    }else{
    if(topLG.hasAttribute("style")){
        topLG.removeAttribute("style");
    }

}
```

}

```
var scrollDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("scrollContent");
for (var i =0; i<scrollDivs.length; i++){
     scrollDivs[i].addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll(scrollDivs[i]), false)
}
```

Comment: Just a note, I understand I can use a for loop to find the objects by classname and then add the event listener. But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way. Or is in lining them the same?

Comment: Why can you try jquery ?

Comment: Using a loop is pretty much how I'd do it as well. You could use jQuery for some syntactic sugar.

Comment: I don't like jquery; just OCD about importing stuff I won't use.

Comment: @christian314159 If I use a loop does it effectivly pass the object to the listener. So say I had `scrollDiv[2].addEventListener("sroll", checkScroll(scrollDivs[2]),false) ` ... When I scroll on the said div element will it be able to pass the div so I can get the children

Comment: post some code if you can

Comment: You can use `this` in your event listener callback function to access the element that the event happened on. Your code above wouldn't work because you are already invoking `checkScroll` when you pass it to the addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**event delegation**](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Something like:

```
// somecontainerDiv can be document, document.body or any Element 
// containing your elements having class 'scrollContent'
somecontainerDiv.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandling);
function scrollHandling(e){
  var originator = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (!/scrollContent/i.test(originator.className) {return true;}
  return checkScroll(e); // or insert checkScroll code here
}
```